# Slim - Trying to get property 'senha' of non-object in

Tags: php, slim, postman

Boa noite.

Estou fazendo um trabalho para faculdade que envolve login..

Estou usando o post pra puxar as requisições e está me dando o seguinte erro:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>: Trying to get property 'senha' of non-object in
<b>C:\wamp64\www\programacao-internet-2\biblioteca_\UsuarioController.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />
```

Tipo post, a url: localhost:8080/api/login
e no body:

```
{
    "email":"admin@teste.com.br",
    "senha": 5667
}
```

Meu arquivo UsuarioController.php ta assim:

```
public function autenticar($request, $response, $args){
            $body = $request->getParsedBody();

            $dao = new UsuarioDAO;

            $usuario = $dao->buscarPorEmail($body['email']);
            if($usuario->senha == $body['senha']){
                $token = array(
                    'user' => strval($usuario->id),
                    'nome' => $usuario->nome
                );

                $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $this->key);
                return $response->withJson(['token' =>$jwt, 201])
                                ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            }else{
                return $response->withStatus(401);
            }
        }
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigada desde já!

Comment: Esse erro quer dizer que você tá tentando acessar um atributo de uma variável que não é um objeto. Pelo que parece, o erro tá na função "buscarPorEmail()", pois é daí que você está tentando extrair atributos de um objeto.

Comment: Olá Thaty, sua pergunta carece de detalhes, é importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Dessa forma poderemos ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema esteja no seu DAO.

O erro deve estar no `$usuario->senha`, provavelmente seu método `buscarPorEmail()` não está retornando um objeto e sim um array de objetos.

Verifique no seu arquivo de **UsuarioDAO** se o método `buscarPorEmail()` está usando fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) em vez de fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ), se for fetchAll, mesmo que só um resultado, o retorno sera um array, então você mudaria `if($usuario->senha == $body['senha']){` para `if($usuario[0]->senha == $body['senha']){`

Comment: A minha função buscarPorEmail, ta assim:  public function buscarPorEmail($email){
        $selectEmail = 'SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE email=:email';
        $pdo = Conexao::getConexao();

        $c = $pdo->prepare($selectEmail);
        $c->bindParam ('email', $email);
        $c->execute();
        $c->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE);
        
        $obj = $c->fetch();

        return $obj;
    }

Comment: Troque as linhas:
$c->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE);
e
$obj = $c->fetch();
Por:
$c->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);